# After enable hive catalog cache on EMR Trino cluster, primary node cannot talk with core nodes correctly

Tags: caching, hive, amazon-emr, presto, trino

I am following this doc https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive-caching.html to enable hive catalog cache on AWS EMR, after adding

```
hive.cache.enabled=true
hive.cache.location=/var/lib/trino/cache1
```

to the hive connector properties, and spin up the EMR cluster, the command from trino-cli `show catalogs` timed out with error
`Insufficient active worker nodes. Waited 5.00m for at least 1 workers, but only 0 workers are active`, without the setting, the connection works fine
from the server log

```
                       Percentage of parquet files to validate after write by re-reading the whole file
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.cache.bookkeeper-port                                       8899                 8899
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.cache.location                                              ----                 /var/lib/trino/cache1
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.cache.ttl                                                   7.00d                7.00d                       Time files will be kept in cache prior to eviction
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.cache.data-transfer-port                                    8898                 8898
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.cache.disk-usage-percentage                                 80                   80                       Percentage of disk space used for cached data
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.cache.stale-fileinfo-expiry-period                          36000                36000
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.cache.file-staleness-check-enable                           true                 true
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.cache.read-mode                                             ASYNC                ASYNC
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.cache.start-server-on-coordinator                           false                false
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.cache.enabled                                               false                true                       Experimental: Cache HDFS file segments to distributed local storage
2023-07-26T18:31:20.139Z        INFO    main    Bootstrap       hive.s3-file-system-type                                         TRINO                EMRFS
```

I do see the cache is bootstrapped correctly

any thoughts?

tried to enable hive catalog cache, and primary node cannot connect to work node. Expect the primary node and work node connect correctly as before enable the hive cache